How are types generated react-relay re-used in functions and components without a GraphQL query?
I prefer to use as many types generated by react-relay for shared logic and components that do not contain a graphql query. How are these types shared without causing cyclical dependencies and long import paths to ../../../foo/bar/__generated__/../..ts?
